# how can I prevent sending that posts to webhook address?

Tags: telegram, webhooks

I have added a robot to my telegram channel.
The robot send all the channel posts to that address that is set in Webhook.
how can I prevent sending that posts to Webhook address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specific `allowed_updates` in setWebhook method, see following instance:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]